# SELECT Top n for multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a “Select top n for group” question except I have 4 tables and need the MAX of several fields.

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.Id, p.Description AS Pathway, CONVERT(Varchar(10), s.CreateDate, 101)
  AS [Date], s.OptionId, o.Description AS Options, s.Score, o.Risk
FROM ucare.Responses r
INNER JOIN ucare.RiskScores s ON s.ScheduleId = r.ScheduleId 
INNER JOIN ucare.PathwayOptions o ON o.Id = s.OptionId
INNER JOIN ucare.Pathways p ON p.Id = r.PathwayId
WHERE r.PathwayId IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT PathwayId
    FROM ucare.Responses 
    WHERE r.ScheduleId = '541')
  AND Score IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(Score) OVER (PARTITION BY s.OptionId) 
    FROM ucare.RiskScores WHERE ScheduleId = '541')
  AND o.Risk IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(Risk) OVER (PARTITION BY o.Id) AS Risk
    FROM ucare.PathwayOptions)
GROUP BY r.Id, s.OptionId, p.Description, s.Score, s.CreateDate, o.Description, o.Risk
```

With the results:

```
**Id    Pathway         Date      OptionId  Options          Score  Risk**
  1    Test pathway 1   6/19/2017   4       Test Option 1     160   10
  10   Test pathway 2   6/19/2017   4       Test Option 1     160   10
  17   Test pathway 3   6/19/2017   4       Test Option 1     160   10
```

What I need is:

```
**Id    Pathway         Date      OptionId  Options         Score   Risk**
  1    Test pathway 1   6/19/2017   4       Test Option 1     160     10
  10   Test pathway 2   6/19/2017   34      Test Option 2     62      10
  17   Test pathway 3   6/19/2017   49      Test Option 3     50       2
```

Where the OptionId, Option (o.Description), Score and Risk change when the Id changes.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks,

Jack

As far as a narrative this sums up what I'm looking for. First we grab all the Responses (ucare.Responses) associated with a specific ScheduleId, in this case 541. This will give us the DISTINCT PathwayId’s of 1, 10 and 17 which are linked to the lookup table of ucare.Pathways for the Pathway Description.

From here the ScheduleId of 541 links ucare.RiskScores which gives us the PathwayOptionsId’s, CreateDate’s and the Scores. The PathwayOptionId is used to link to the Id field in ucare.PathwayOptions table where we can get the matching PathwayOption Description, the most recent (MAX(CreateDate)) and the matching MAX(Risk).

The MAX Risk is used to break any ties that exist for the RiskScore. For instance if we query ucare.RiskScores  with the ScheduleId of 541 there are 4 matching PathwayOptionId’s, 1, 2, 4 and 5 with a Score of 160, but with the Risk of 8, 7, 10, and 9. Choice #4 has a MAX Score of 160 and a MAX Risk of 10, so that is our choice.
This would complete the linking chain for ScheduleId 541.

This is the new CREATE/INSERT script which has all the fields and appropriate data to match.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [ucare].[PathwayOptions](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Risk] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PathwayId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Range] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ucare.PathwayOptions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ucare].[PathwayOptions] ON
INSERT [ucare].[PathwayOptions] ([Id], [Title], [Description], [Risk], [PathwayId], [Range]) VALUES 
(1, N'COPD B', N'GOLD Risk Level B - Low Risk, High Symptom', 8, 1, NULL),
(2, N'COPD A', N'GOLD Risk Level A - Low Risk, Low Symptom', 7, 1, NULL),
(4, N'COPD D', N'GOLD Risk Level D - High Risk, High Symptom', 10, 1, NULL),
(5, N'COPD C', N'GOLD Risk Level C - High Risk, Low Symptom', 9, 1, NULL),
(6, N'TKA PT High Fxn', N'High FxnTKA', 7, 2, NULL),
(7, N'TKA PT', N'TKA High Function', 7, 2, NULL),
(9, N'TKA PT', N'TKA Med', 9, 2, NULL),
(12, N'Fall Risk - High', N'Rehab Fall Risk - High', 10, 5, NULL),
(13, N'Fall Risk - Medium', N'Rehab Fall Risk - Medium', 9, 5, NULL),
(14, N'Fall Risk - Low', N'Rehab Fall Risk - Low', 8, 5, NULL),
(15, N'High Fall Risk', N'High Risk of Falling', 10, 4, NULL),
(16, N'Low Fall Risk', N'Low Risk of Falling', 8, 4, NULL),
(17, N'Primary Prevention 2', N'Primary Prevention Level 2', 6, 7, NULL),
(18, N'Primary Prevention 1', N'Primary Prevention Level 1', 5, 7, NULL),
(21, N'Stable/Improving', N'No significant changes', 7, 8, NULL),
(22, N'Mixed Change', N'Mixed results from assessment', 8, 8, NULL),
(23, N'Significant Decline', N'Observation shows marked decline in condition', 9, 8, NULL),
(24, N'High Alert', N'Results require an immediate alert', 10, 8, NULL),
(25, N'Secondary Prevention 1', N'Secondary Prevention Level 1', 7, 7, NULL),
(26, N'Secondary Prevention 2', N'Secondary Prevention Level 2', 8, 7, NULL),
(27, N'Tertiary Prevention', N'Tertiary Prevention', 9, 7, NULL),
(28, N'Catastrophic Care', N'Catastrophic Care', 10, 7, NULL),
(29, N'Grade 0', N'Grade 0', 0, 9, NULL),
(30, N'Grade 1', N'Grade 1', 1, 9, NULL),
(31, N'Grade 2', N'Grade 2', 2, 9, NULL),
(32, N'Grade 3', N'Grade 3', 3, 9, NULL),
(33, N'Grade 4', N'Grade 4', 4, 9, NULL),
(34, N'High Risk', N'High Risk of OSA', 10, 10, N'5-8'),
(35, N'Low Risk', N'Low Risk of OSA', 8, 10, N'0-2'),
(36, N'Low Fall Risk', N'Low Risk of Falling', 9, 6, NULL),
(37, N'High Fall Risk', N'High Risk of Falling', 10, 6, NULL),
(38, N'Current Placement Appropriate', N'The current care setting is appropriate', 8, 11, NULL),
(39, N'Consider New Placement', N'Higher level care may be necessary', 9, 11, NULL),
(40, N'New Placement Needed', N'Higher level of care is strongly recommended', 10, 11, NULL),
(41, N'Driving is Appropriate', N'No significant signs of driving danger', 7, 12, NULL),
(42, N'Monitor Driving Safety', N'Continue to Monitor the Driving Safety', 8, 12, NULL),
(43, N'Driving Safety is a Concern', N'Consider restricting or removing from driving', 9, 12, NULL),
(44, N'Driving is Not Appropriate', N'Driving should not be allowed', 10, 12, NULL),
(45, N'No current needs', N'No home service needs', 9, 13, NULL),
(46, N'Some Home Service Needs', N'Home service needed', 10, 13, NULL),
(47, N'Hi Risk', N'High Fall Risk', 10, 16, NULL),
(48, N'Lo Risk ', N'Low Fall Risk', 9, 16, NULL),
(49, N'Low Risk', N'Low risk range', 0, 17, N'1-2'),
(50, N'Medium Risk', N'Medium risk option', 1, 17, N'6-10'),
(51, N'High Risk', N'High risk option', 2, 17, N'11-15'),
(52, N'Intermediate Risk', N'Intermediate Rsk of OSA', 9, 10, N'3-4'),
(53, N'Lo Fall', N'Low Fall Risk', 9, 18, NULL),
(54, N'Very High', N'Very High Impact', 10, 25, N'31-50'),
(55, N'High', N'High Impact Level', 9, 25, N'21-30'),
(56, N'Medium', N'Medium Impact Level', 8, 25, N'10-20'),
(57, N'Low', N'Low Impact Level', 7, 25, N'6-9'),
(58, N'None', N'No Impact', 6, 25, N'0-5')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ucare].[PathwayOptions] OFF

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [ucare].[Responses](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Text] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PathwayOptionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DecisionInputId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ScheduleId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EntryDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [PathwayId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EncounterId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EpisodeId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ucare.Responses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ucare].[Responses] ON
INSERT [ucare].[Responses] ([Id], [Text], [PathwayOptionId], [DecisionInputId], [ScheduleId], [EntryDate], [PathwayId], [EncounterId], [EpisodeId]) VALUES 
(1179, N'True', 0, 17, 543, CAST(0x0000A7940067AC73 AS DateTime), 17, 543, 1),
(1180, N'True', 0, 130, 543, CAST(0x0000A7940067AC73 AS DateTime), 17, 543,1),
(1181, N'True', 0, 16, 543, CAST(0x0000A7940067AC73 AS DateTime), 17, 543, 1),
(1182, N'True', 0, 76, 543, CAST(0x0000A7940067AC73 AS DateTime), 17, 543, 1),
(1183, N'34', 0, 38, 543, CAST(0x0000A79400578978 AS DateTime), 17, 543, 1),
(1184, N'True', 0, 82, 543, CAST(0x0000A79400578978 AS DateTime), 17, 543, 1),
(1185, N'True', 0, 17, 543, CAST(0x0000A79400578978 AS DateTime), 17, 543, 1),
(1186, N'True', 0, 130, 543, CAST(0x0000A79400578978 AS DateTime), 17, 543, 1),
(1187, N'True', 0, 16, 543, CAST(0x0000A79400578978 AS DateTime), 17, 543, 1),
(1188, N'True', 0, 76, 543, CAST(0x0000A79400578978 AS DateTime), 17, 543, 1),
(1189, N'34', 0, 38, 543, CAST(0x0000A79400579A40 AS DateTime), 17, 543, 1),
(1190, N'True', 0, 82, 543, CAST(0x0000A79400579A40 AS DateTime), 17, 543, 1),
(1191, N'True', 0, 17, 543, CAST(0x0000A79400579A40 AS DateTime), 17, 543, 1),
(1192, N'False', 0, 130, 543, CAST(0x0000A79400579A40 AS DateTime), 17, 543, 1),
(1193, N'False', 0, 16, 543, CAST(0x0000A79400579A40 AS DateTime), 17, 543, 1),
(1194, N'False', 0, 76, 543, CAST(0x0000A79400579A40 AS DateTime), 17, 543, 1),
(1195, N'2', 0, 66, 541, CAST(0x0000A7970091A833 AS DateTime), 1, 541, 1),
(1196, N'2', 0, 67, 541, CAST(0x0000A7970091A833 AS DateTime), 1, 541, 1),
(1197, N'3', 0, 68, 541, CAST(0x0000A7970091A833 AS DateTime), 1, 541, 1),
(1198, N'False', 0, 65, 541, CAST(0x0000A7970091A833 AS DateTime), 1, 541, 1),
(1199, N'12', 0, 39, 541, CAST(0x0000A7970091A833 AS DateTime), 1, 541, 1),
(1200, N'1', 0, 66, 541, CAST(0x0000A797009281A8 AS DateTime), 1, 541, 1),
(1201, N'1', 0, 67, 541, CAST(0x0000A797009281A8 AS DateTime), 1, 541, 1),
(1202, N'1', 0, 68, 541, CAST(0x0000A797009281A8 AS DateTime), 1, 541, 1),
(1203, N'False', 0, 65, 541, CAST(0x0000A797009281A8 AS DateTime), 1, 541, 1),
(1204, N'9', 0, 39, 541, CAST(0x0000A797009281A8 AS DateTime), 1, 541, 1),
(1205, N'', 0, 38, 541, CAST(0x0000A7970095C348 AS DateTime), 17, 541, 1),
(1206, N'True', 0, 82, 541, CAST(0x0000A7970095C348 AS DateTime), 17, 541, 1),
(1207, N'True', 0, 17, 541, CAST(0x0000A7970095C348 AS DateTime), 17, 541, 1),
(1208, N'False', 0, 130, 541, CAST(0x0000A7970095C348 AS DateTime), 17, 541, 1),
(1209, N'False', 0, 16, 541, CAST(0x0000A7970095C348 AS DateTime), 17, 541, 1),
(1210, N'True', 0, 76, 541, CAST(0x0000A7970095C348 AS DateTime), 17, 541, 1),
(1211, N'True', 0, 92, 541, CAST(0x0000A79700973842 AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1212, N'False', 0, 93, 541, CAST(0x0000A79700973842 AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1213, N'False', 0, 94, 541, CAST(0x0000A79700973842 AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1214, N'True', 0, 95, 541, CAST(0x0000A79700973842 AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1215, N'True', 0, 96, 541, CAST(0x0000A79700973842 AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1216, NULL, 0, 97, 541, CAST(0x0000A79700973842 AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1217, N'True', 0, 98, 541, CAST(0x0000A79700973842 AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1218, N'True', 0, 99, 541, CAST(0x0000A79700973842 AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1219, N'True', 0, 92, 541, CAST(0x0000A79700974DEC AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1220, N'False', 0, 93, 541, CAST(0x0000A79700974DEC AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1221, N'False', 0, 94, 541, CAST(0x0000A79700974DEC AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1222, N'True', 0, 95, 541, CAST(0x0000A79700974DEC AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1223, N'False', 0, 96, 541, CAST(0x0000A79700974DEC AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1224, NULL, 0, 97, 541, CAST(0x0000A79700974DEC AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1225, N'True', 0, 98, 541, CAST(0x0000A79700974DEC AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1226, N'True', 0, 99, 541, CAST(0x0000A79700974DEC AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1227, N'False', 0, 92, 541, CAST(0x0000A797009756C0 AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1228, N'False', 0, 93, 541, CAST(0x0000A797009756C0 AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1229, N'False', 0, 94, 541, CAST(0x0000A797009756C0 AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1230, N'False', 0, 95, 541, CAST(0x0000A797009756C0 AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1231, N'False', 0, 96, 541, CAST(0x0000A797009756C0 AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1232, NULL, 0, 97, 541, CAST(0x0000A797009756C0 AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1233, N'True', 0, 98, 541, CAST(0x0000A797009756C0 AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1234, N'True', 0, 99, 541, CAST(0x0000A797009756C0 AS DateTime), 10, 541, 1),
(1235, N'True', 0, 92, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800A381F1 AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1236, N'False', 0, 93, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800A381F1 AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1237, N'False', 0, 94, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800A381F1 AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1238, N'True', 0, 95, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800A381F1 AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1239, N'True', 0, 96, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800A381F1 AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1240, NULL, 0, 97, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800A381F1 AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1241, NULL, 0, 98, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800A381F1 AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1242, NULL, 0, 99, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800A381F1 AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1243, N'False', 0, 92, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800AE690E AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1244, N'True', 0, 93, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800AE690E AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1245, N'False', 0, 94, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800AE690E AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1246, N'True', 0, 95, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800AE690E AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1247, NULL, 0, 96, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800AE690E AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1248, N'False', 0, 97, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800AE690E AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1249, N'True', 0, 98, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800AE690E AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1250, NULL, 0, 99, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800AE690E AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1251, N'False', 0, 92, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800AFFEE6 AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1252, N'True', 0, 93, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800AFFEE6 AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1253, N'False', 0, 94, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800AFFEE6 AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1254, N'True', 0, 95, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800AFFEE6 AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1255, NULL, 0, 96, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800AFFEE6 AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1256, N'True', 0, 97, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800AFFEE6 AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1257, N'True', 0, 98, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800AFFEE6 AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1258, N'True', 0, 99, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800AFFEE6 AS DateTime), 10, 540, 1),
(1259, N'2', 0, 66, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800B0493B AS DateTime), 1, 540, 1),
(1260, N'3', 0, 67, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800B0493B AS DateTime), 1, 540, 1),
(1261, N'3', 0, 68, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800B0493B AS DateTime), 1, 540, 1),
(1262, N'True', 0, 65, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800B0493B AS DateTime), 1, 540, 1),
(1263, N'12', 0, 39, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800B0493B AS DateTime), 1, 540, 1),
(1264, N'0', 0, 66, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800B087C5 AS DateTime), 1, 540, 1),
(1265, N'3', 0, 67, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800B087C5 AS DateTime), 1, 540, 1),
(1266, N'4', 0, 68, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800B087C5 AS DateTime), 1, 540, 1),
(1267, N'True', 0, 65, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800B087C5 AS DateTime), 1, 540, 1),
(1268, N'12', 0, 39, 540, CAST(0x0000A79800B087C5 AS DateTime), 1, 540, 1),
(1269, N'23', 0, 38, 356, CAST(0x0000A79900D5FDCC AS DateTime), 17, 356, 1),
(1270, N'True', 0, 82, 356, CAST(0x0000A79900D5FDCC AS DateTime), 17, 356, 1),
(1271, N'False', 0, 17, 356, CAST(0x0000A79900D5FDCC AS DateTime), 17, 356, 1),
(1272, N'True', 0, 130, 356, CAST(0x0000A79900D5FDCC AS DateTime), 17, 356, 1),
(1273, N'True', 0, 16, 356, CAST(0x0000A79900D5FDCC AS DateTime), 17, 356, 1),
(1274, N'True', 0, 76, 356, CAST(0x0000A79900D5FDCC AS DateTime), 17, 356, 1),
(1275, N'1', 0, 66, 356, CAST(0x0000A79A0098DF24 AS DateTime), 1, 356, 1),
(1276, N'1', 0, 67, 356, CAST(0x0000A79A0098DF24 AS DateTime), 1, 356, 1),
(1277, N'1', 0, 68, 356, CAST(0x0000A79A0098DF24 AS DateTime), 1, 356, 1),
(1278, N'False', 0, 65, 356, CAST(0x0000A79A0098DF24 AS DateTime), 1, 356, 1),
(1279, N'9', 0, 39, 356, CAST(0x0000A79A0098DF24 AS DateTime), 1, 356, 1)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ucare].[Responses] OFF
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [ucare].[RiskScores](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ScheduleId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PathwayOptionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Score] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [varchar](200) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ucare].[RiskScores] ON
INSERT [ucare].[RiskScores] ([Id], [ScheduleId], [PathwayOptionId], [Score], [CreateDate], [CreatedBy]) VALUES 
(1, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77500E986A9 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(2, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77500E9CD16 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(3, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77500EA13CB AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(4, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600A7A764 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(5, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600A7B604 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(6, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600A83653 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(7, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600A9486B AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(8, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600A981A9 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(9, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600AB4821 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(10, 2, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600AC0883 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(11, 2, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600B25DF2 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(12, 2, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600B2F07C AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(13, 2, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600DEDD85 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(14, 2, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600DF5E89 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(15, 2, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600DF8575 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(16, 2, 1, 0, CAST(0x0000A77B00B0F7C4 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(17, 2, 2, 0, CAST(0x0000A77B00B0F7C4 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(18, 2, 4, 20, CAST(0x0000A77B00B0F7C4 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(19, 2, 5, 20, CAST(0x0000A77B00B0F7C4 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(20, 2, 1, 60, CAST(0x0000A77B00B150AE AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(21, 2, 2, 60, CAST(0x0000A77B00B150AE AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(22, 2, 4, 40, CAST(0x0000A77B00B150AE AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(23, 2, 5, 40, CAST(0x0000A77B00B150AE AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(24, 2, 1, 60, CAST(0x0000A77B00BD3FDA AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(25, 2, 2, 60, CAST(0x0000A77B00BD3FDA AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(26, 2, 4, 40, CAST(0x0000A77B00BD3FDA AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(27, 2, 5, 40, CAST(0x0000A77B00BD3FDA AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(28, 2, 15, 14, CAST(0x0000A77B00BD832E AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(29, 2, 16, 14, CAST(0x0000A77B00BD832E AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1002, 2, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77C0070AE72 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1003, 2, 1, 60, CAST(0x0000A77C0070C1E6 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1004, 2, 2, 60, CAST(0x0000A77C0070C1E6 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1005, 2, 4, 40, CAST(0x0000A77C0070C1E6 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1006, 2, 5, 40, CAST(0x0000A77C0070C1E6 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1007, 2, 49, 16, CAST(0x0000A79100E87601 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1008, 2, 50, 16, CAST(0x0000A79100E87601 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1009, 2, 51, 16, CAST(0x0000A79100E87601 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1016, 2, 49, 50, CAST(0x0000A79100FADB8A AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1017, 2, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A79100FD7090 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1018, 2, 49, 16, CAST(0x0000A79100FDB842 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1025, 543, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A794006340B9 AS DateTime),  N'Admin'),
(1026, 543, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A79400639285 AS DateTime),  N'Admin'),
(1027, 543, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A7940063D4EE AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1028, 543, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A7940063E528 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1029, 543, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A79400644580 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1030, 543, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A79400649B97 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1031, 543, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A79400663C8F AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1033, 543, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A79400578978 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1034, 543, 49, 50, CAST(0x0000A79400579A40 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1035, 541, 1, 160, CAST(0x0000A7970091A833 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1036, 541, 2, 0, CAST(0x0000A7970091A833 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1037, 541, 4, 160, CAST(0x0000A7970091A833 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1038, 541, 5, 0, CAST(0x0000A7970091A833 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1039, 541, 1, 0, CAST(0x0000A797009281A8 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1040, 541, 2, 160, CAST(0x0000A797009281A8 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1041, 541, 4, 0, CAST(0x0000A797009281A8 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1042, 541, 5, 160, CAST(0x0000A797009281A8 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1043, 541, 49, 50, CAST(0x0000A7970095C348 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1044, 541, 34, 62, CAST(0x0000A79700973842 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1045, 541, 52, 50, CAST(0x0000A79700974DEC AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1046, 541, 35, 25, CAST(0x0000A797009756C0 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1049, 540, 34, 62, CAST(0x0000A79800AFFEE6 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1050, 540, 1, 160, CAST(0x0000A79800B0493B AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1051, 540, 2, 0, CAST(0x0000A79800B0493B AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1052, 540, 4, 160, CAST(0x0000A79800B0493B AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1053, 540, 5, 0, CAST(0x0000A79800B0493B AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1054, 540, 1, 160, CAST(0x0000A79800B087C5 AS DateTime), N'Admin')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ucare].[RiskScores] OFF

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [ucare].[Pathways](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PatientPathway_Id] [int] NULL,
    [CalculationType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Instructions] [varchar](400) NULL,
    [RecordStatus] [char](1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ucare.Pathways] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ucare].[Pathways] ON
INSERT [ucare].[Pathways] ([Id], [Title], [Description]) VALUES 
(1, N'COPD GOLD Risk Classification', N'COPD GOLD Classification'),
(2, N'TKA PT', N'Physical Therapy TKA'),
(4, N'Fall Assess - RN', N'Medical Fall Risk Screen'),
(5, N'Fall Assess - Rehab', N'Rehab Specialist Fall Assessment'),
(6, N'Fall Assess - Caregiver', N'Caregiver Fall Assessment'),
(7, N'Global Risk', N'Global Risk Stratification'),
(8, N'COPD Assess - RT', N'COPD Assessment - Respiratory Therapist'),
(9, N'MMRC Test', N'MMRC Dyspnea Test'),
(10, N'STOP BANG ', N'Stop Bang Assessment'),
(11, N'Care Placement Needs Assessment', N'Assessment for Patient Placement'),
(12, N'Driving Assessment', N'Driving Ability Assessemnt'),
(13, N'Home Care Needs Assessment', N'Home Care Needs Assessment'),
(14, N'Home Services Needs Assessment', N'Assessment to the specific needs for home services'),
(15, N'DbCustomerTest', N'Testing-1'),
(16, N'FRAT Assessment', N'Fall Risk Assessment'),
(17, N'A - Test Count Pathway', N'Test pathway for updated count scoring algorithm'),
(18, N'FRAT Assessment', N'Fall Risk Assessment'),
(21, N'AAA Test', N'Test'),
(25, N'CAT', N'COPD Assessment Test (CAT)')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ucare].[Pathways] OFF
```

Comment: sample data please

Comment: The short answer "CROSS APPLY SELECT TOP N <rows> FROM ... ORDER BY ...) If you want a better answer, please provide test data inthe form of create table and insert data scripts.

Comment: I do not see a TOP n in your query, and I don't know what is a "Top n for group" question. Would you please provide an explanation?

Comment: Building the INSERT query now. There are several Select the MAX/MIN for this group questions on SO, that's what I was getting at.

Comment: Omit `s.Score` and `o.risk` from your `group by` clause, and add `max(s.Score)` and `max(o.risk)` to your output? Is that all you need?

Comment: Xedni - Thanks for your reply but I'm getting the error, "Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause." when I change the Group By. This is a SQL Server 2008 R2 query.

Comment: Ah, I see. Try Selecting out the data without doing your group by. Then wrap that whole thing in a subquery. You should be able to use your group by on that subquery instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tables but not quite helpful as your query calls fields not included.

Comment: Looking at the Responses table, all ScheduleIDs are 541.. And looking at RiskScores, all but 1 has a ScheduleID of 541... So joining the two tables is on r.ScheduleId = s.ScheduleId is going to create a Cartesian product.

Comment: Can you provide a narrative or schema to the table relationships?

Comment: I had to scrub some tables because of HIPAA concerns I'll redo the CREATE/INSERT. Thanks Parfait and Jason for pointing the errors.

Comment: As long as you aren't including any PII (personally identifiable information), there shouldn't be HIPPA issues. I don't see anything that even remotely looks like patient information. The key is, you have to be able to tell us what the expected results should look like **based on the sample data you provide**. Saying, "CTE has several dupes and only includes 2 of 3 OptionId", doesn't help when you can't point to a bad join or show where the 3rd OptionId joins to the rest of the data.

Comment: Looking at the new data... The Pathways table has 8 columns but you insert only has 3...

Comment: I've updated my original answer. See below.

Comment: Excellent Jason! A very complex scenario scenario that you handled, very nice solution, I'd tried RowNumber, Rank, several different JOINs but not a CTE nicely done. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this is what you're looking for... (also changed the tables to #TempTables for anyone else who wants to play along without adding a new schema and real tables to their test environment)

EDIT: New solution has been added based on new data for OP.

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PathwayOptions', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #PathwayOptions;
GO 
CREATE TABLE #PathwayOptions(
    Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ,
    Title nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    Description nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    Risk int NOT NULL,
    PathwayId int NOT NULL,
    Range varchar(50) NULL
    );
GO
INSERT #PathwayOptions (Id, Title, Description, Risk, PathwayId, Range) VALUES 
(1, N'COPD B', N'GOLD Risk Level B - Low Risk, High Symptom', 8, 1, NULL),
(2, N'COPD A', N'GOLD Risk Level A - Low Risk, Low Symptom', 7, 1, NULL),
(4, N'COPD D', N'GOLD Risk Level D - High Risk, High Symptom', 10, 1, NULL),
(5, N'COPD C', N'GOLD Risk Level C - High Risk, Low Symptom', 9, 1, NULL),
(6, N'TKA PT High Fxn', N'High FxnTKA', 7, 2, NULL),
(7, N'TKA PT', N'TKA High Function', 7, 2, NULL),
(9, N'TKA PT', N'TKA Med', 9, 2, NULL),
(12, N'Fall Risk - High', N'Rehab Fall Risk - High', 10, 5, NULL),
(13, N'Fall Risk - Medium', N'Rehab Fall Risk - Medium', 9, 5, NULL),
(14, N'Fall Risk - Low', N'Rehab Fall Risk - Low', 8, 5, NULL),
(15, N'High Fall Risk', N'High Risk of Falling', 10, 4, NULL),
(16, N'Low Fall Risk', N'Low Risk of Falling', 8, 4, NULL),
(17, N'Primary Prevention 2', N'Primary Prevention Level 2', 6, 7, NULL),
(18, N'Primary Prevention 1', N'Primary Prevention Level 1', 5, 7, NULL),
(21, N'Stable/Improving', N'No significant changes', 7, 8, NULL),
(22, N'Mixed Change', N'Mixed results from assessment', 8, 8, NULL),
(23, N'Significant Decline', N'Observation shows marked decline in condition', 9, 8, NULL),
(24, N'High Alert', N'Results require an immediate alert', 10, 8, NULL),
(25, N'Secondary Prevention 1', N'Secondary Prevention Level 1', 7, 7, NULL),
(26, N'Secondary Prevention 2', N'Secondary Prevention Level 2', 8, 7, NULL),
(27, N'Tertiary Prevention', N'Tertiary Prevention', 9, 7, NULL),
(28, N'Catastrophic Care', N'Catastrophic Care', 10, 7, NULL),
(29, N'Grade 0', N'Grade 0', 0, 9, NULL),
(30, N'Grade 1', N'Grade 1', 1, 9, NULL),
(31, N'Grade 2', N'Grade 2', 2, 9, NULL),
(32, N'Grade 3', N'Grade 3', 3, 9, NULL),
(33, N'Grade 4', N'Grade 4', 4, 9, NULL),
(34, N'High Risk', N'High Risk of OSA', 10, 10, N'5-8'),
(35, N'Low Risk', N'Low Risk of OSA', 8, 10, N'0-2'),
(36, N'Low Fall Risk', N'Low Risk of Falling', 9, 6, NULL),
(37, N'High Fall Risk', N'High Risk of Falling', 10, 6, NULL),
(38, N'Current Placement Appropriate', N'The current care setting is appropriate', 8, 11, NULL),
(39, N'Consider New Placement', N'Higher level care may be necessary', 9, 11, NULL),
(40, N'New Placement Needed', N'Higher level of care is strongly recommended', 10, 11, NULL),
(41, N'Driving is Appropriate', N'No significant signs of driving danger', 7, 12, NULL),
(42, N'Monitor Driving Safety', N'Continue to Monitor the Driving Safety', 8, 12, NULL),
(43, N'Driving Safety is a Concern', N'Consider restricting or removing from driving', 9, 12, NULL),
(44, N'Driving is Not Appropriate', N'Driving should not be allowed', 10, 12, NULL),
(45, N'No current needs', N'No home service needs', 9, 13, NULL),
(46, N'Some Home Service Needs', N'Home service needed', 10, 13, NULL),
(47, N'Hi Risk', N'High Fall Risk', 10, 16, NULL),
(48, N'Lo Risk ', N'Low Fall Risk', 9, 16, NULL),
(49, N'Low Risk', N'Low risk range', 0, 17, N'1-2'),
(50, N'Medium Risk', N'Medium risk option', 1, 17, N'6-10'),
(51, N'High Risk', N'High risk option', 2, 17, N'11-15'),
(52, N'Intermediate Risk', N'Intermediate Rsk of OSA', 9, 10, N'3-4'),
(53, N'Lo Fall', N'Low Fall Risk', 9, 18, NULL),
(54, N'Very High', N'Very High Impact', 10, 25, N'31-50'),
(55, N'High', N'High Impact Level', 9, 25, N'21-30'),
(56, N'Medium', N'Medium Impact Level', 8, 25, N'10-20'),
(57, N'Low', N'Low Impact Level', 7, 25, N'6-9'),
(58, N'None', N'No Impact', 6, 25, N'0-5');
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RiskScores', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #RiskScores;
go 
CREATE TABLE #RiskScores(
    Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    ScheduleId int NOT NULL,
    PathwayOptionId int NOT NULL,
    Score int NOT NULL,
    CreateDate datetime NULL,
    CreatedBy varchar(200) NULL
    );
GO 
INSERT #RiskScores (Id, ScheduleId, PathwayOptionId, Score, CreateDate, CreatedBy) VALUES 
(1, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77500E986A9 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(2, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77500E9CD16 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(3, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77500EA13CB AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(4, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600A7A764 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(5, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600A7B604 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(6, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600A83653 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(7, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600A9486B AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(8, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600A981A9 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(9, 1, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600AB4821 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(10, 2, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600AC0883 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(11, 2, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600B25DF2 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(12, 2, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600B2F07C AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(13, 2, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600DEDD85 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(14, 2, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600DF5E89 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(15, 2, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77600DF8575 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(16, 2, 1, 0, CAST(0x0000A77B00B0F7C4 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(17, 2, 2, 0, CAST(0x0000A77B00B0F7C4 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(18, 2, 4, 20, CAST(0x0000A77B00B0F7C4 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(19, 2, 5, 20, CAST(0x0000A77B00B0F7C4 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(20, 2, 1, 60, CAST(0x0000A77B00B150AE AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(21, 2, 2, 60, CAST(0x0000A77B00B150AE AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(22, 2, 4, 40, CAST(0x0000A77B00B150AE AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(23, 2, 5, 40, CAST(0x0000A77B00B150AE AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(24, 2, 1, 60, CAST(0x0000A77B00BD3FDA AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(25, 2, 2, 60, CAST(0x0000A77B00BD3FDA AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(26, 2, 4, 40, CAST(0x0000A77B00BD3FDA AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(27, 2, 5, 40, CAST(0x0000A77B00BD3FDA AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(28, 2, 15, 14, CAST(0x0000A77B00BD832E AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(29, 2, 16, 14, CAST(0x0000A77B00BD832E AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1002, 2, 14, 0, CAST(0x0000A77C0070AE72 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1003, 2, 1, 60, CAST(0x0000A77C0070C1E6 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1004, 2, 2, 60, CAST(0x0000A77C0070C1E6 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1005, 2, 4, 40, CAST(0x0000A77C0070C1E6 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1006, 2, 5, 40, CAST(0x0000A77C0070C1E6 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1007, 2, 49, 16, CAST(0x0000A79100E87601 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1008, 2, 50, 16, CAST(0x0000A79100E87601 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1009, 2, 51, 16, CAST(0x0000A79100E87601 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1016, 2, 49, 50, CAST(0x0000A79100FADB8A AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1017, 2, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A79100FD7090 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1018, 2, 49, 16, CAST(0x0000A79100FDB842 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1025, 543, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A794006340B9 AS DateTime),  N'Admin'),
(1026, 543, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A79400639285 AS DateTime),  N'Admin'),
(1027, 543, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A7940063D4EE AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1028, 543, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A7940063E528 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1029, 543, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A79400644580 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1030, 543, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A79400649B97 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1031, 543, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A79400663C8F AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1033, 543, 50, 100, CAST(0x0000A79400578978 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1034, 543, 49, 50, CAST(0x0000A79400579A40 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1035, 541, 1, 160, CAST(0x0000A7970091A833 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1036, 541, 2, 0, CAST(0x0000A7970091A833 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1037, 541, 4, 160, CAST(0x0000A7970091A833 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1038, 541, 5, 0, CAST(0x0000A7970091A833 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1039, 541, 1, 0, CAST(0x0000A797009281A8 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1040, 541, 2, 160, CAST(0x0000A797009281A8 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1041, 541, 4, 0, CAST(0x0000A797009281A8 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1042, 541, 5, 160, CAST(0x0000A797009281A8 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1043, 541, 49, 50, CAST(0x0000A7970095C348 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1044, 541, 34, 62, CAST(0x0000A79700973842 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1045, 541, 52, 50, CAST(0x0000A79700974DEC AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1046, 541, 35, 25, CAST(0x0000A797009756C0 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1049, 540, 34, 62, CAST(0x0000A79800AFFEE6 AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1050, 540, 1, 160, CAST(0x0000A79800B0493B AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1051, 540, 2, 0, CAST(0x0000A79800B0493B AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1052, 540, 4, 160, CAST(0x0000A79800B0493B AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1053, 540, 5, 0, CAST(0x0000A79800B0493B AS DateTime), N'Admin'),
(1054, 540, 1, 160, CAST(0x0000A79800B087C5 AS DateTime), N'Admin');
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Pathways', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Pathways;
GO 
CREATE TABLE #Pathways(
    Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Title nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    Description nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
    --ProviderType nvarchar(max) NULL,
    --PatientPathway_Id int NULL,
    --CalculationType varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    --Instructions varchar(400) NULL,
    --RecordStatus char(1) NOT NULL
    );
GO 
INSERT #Pathways (Id, Title, Description) VALUES 
(1, N'COPD GOLD Risk Classification', N'COPD GOLD Classification'),
(2, N'TKA PT', N'Physical Therapy TKA'),
(4, N'Fall Assess - RN', N'Medical Fall Risk Screen'),
(5, N'Fall Assess - Rehab', N'Rehab Specialist Fall Assessment'),
(6, N'Fall Assess - Caregiver', N'Caregiver Fall Assessment'),
(7, N'Global Risk', N'Global Risk Stratification'),
(8, N'COPD Assess - RT', N'COPD Assessment - Respiratory Therapist'),
(9, N'MMRC Test', N'MMRC Dyspnea Test'),
(10, N'STOP BANG ', N'Stop Bang Assessment'),
(11, N'Care Placement Needs Assessment', N'Assessment for Patient Placement'),
(12, N'Driving Assessment', N'Driving Ability Assessemnt'),
(13, N'Home Care Needs Assessment', N'Home Care Needs Assessment'),
(14, N'Home Services Needs Assessment', N'Assessment to the specific needs for home services'),
(15, N'DbCustomerTest', N'Testing-1'),
(16, N'FRAT Assessment', N'Fall Risk Assessment'),
(17, N'A - Test Count Pathway', N'Test pathway for updated count scoring algorithm'),
(18, N'FRAT Assessment', N'Fall Risk Assessment'),
(21, N'AAA Test', N'Test'),
(25, N'CAT', N'COPD Assessment Test (CAT)');
GO

--SELECT * FROM #Responses r;
--SELECT * FROM #RiskScores rs;
--SELECT * FROM #PathwayOptions po;
--SELECT * FROM #Pathways p;

--====================================================================
--====================================================================

WITH
    cte_PoRs AS (
        SELECT 
            rs.ScheduleId,
            po.PathwayId,
            rs.PathwayOptionId,
            rs.Score,
            po.Risk,
            rs.CreateDate,
            po.Description,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY po.PathwayId ORDER BY rs.Score DESC, po.Risk DESC, rs.CreateDate DESC)
        FROM 
            #PathwayOptions po
            JOIN #RiskScores rs
                ON po.id = rs.PathwayOptionId
        WHERE 
            rs.ScheduleId = 541
        )
SELECT 
    pr.PathwayId,
    Pathway = p.Description,
    [Date] = cast(pr.CreateDate AS DATE),
    OptionId = pr.PathwayOptionId,
    Options = pr.Description,
    pr.Score,
    pr.Risk
FROM 
    cte_PoRs pr
    JOIN #Pathways p
        ON pr.PathwayId = p.Id
WHERE 
    pr.RN = 1;
```

Results...

```
PathwayId   Pathway                                            Date       OptionId    Options                                            Score       Risk
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- -----------
1           COPD GOLD Classification                           2017-06-19 4           GOLD Risk Level D - High Risk, High Symptom        160         10
10          Stop Bang Assessment                               2017-06-19 34          High Risk of OSA                                   62          10
17          Test pathway for updated count scoring algorithm   2017-06-19 49          Low risk range                                     50          0
```

Everything seems to match up to your expected output except for PathwayId 17 having a Risk of 2... I double checked the data... The only [Pathway 17 / Risk 2] combo in the data is for a [ScheduleId 2 / Option 51] and it only has a score of 16. Hope this helps.